# Doubt regarding a lemma

Tags: proof-explanation, convex-analysis, convex-geometry, discrete-geometry

So I am going through [this paper](https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/107241/454_2017_Article_9883.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y).
Could someone please explain how they proved this lemma:

> **Lemma 1.2** Let $I_1,\dots,I_n\subset\mathbb R$ be segments of lengths $\ell_1,\dots,\ell_n$ with midpoints $c_1,\dots,c_n$. Assume the union $\bigcup I_i$ is a segment (i.e. the family of segments is non-separable). Then the segment $I$ of length $\sum \ell_i$ with midpoint at the center of mass $c=\frac{\sum \ell_i c_i}{\sum \ell_i}$ covers $\bigcup I_i$.

P.S. I tried to access the research paper where this is proved but it seems it is not accessible to the public domain.
Thank you!!

Comment: I'm not sure but IMO the proof-writing tag is wrongly used for this question.

Comment: There surely [must be a way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sci-Hub) to get access to the [paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2304537) by Goodman and Goodman.

Comment: @Amelia I have removed it

Comment: @Christoph Oh! I had no idea about this. This is amazing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read  Goodman & Goodman proof and this is a short summery in OP's notations.

Let $\bigcup_{i=1}^n I_i=[a,b]$. We may assume that $I_i=[a_i,b_i]$ with $a=a_1\leq a_2\leq a_3\leq\dots\leq a_n$. Then for any $1\leq i\leq n$,
$$c_i-a=a_i+\frac{l_i}{2}-a\leq l_1+l_2+\dots+l_{i-1}+\frac{l_i}{2}$$
which implies that
$$
\begin{align}c-a&=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n l_i c_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n l_i}-a=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n l_i (c_i-a)}{\sum_{i=1}^n l_i}\\
&\leq \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n l_i \left(l_1+l_2+\dots+l_{i-1}+\frac{l_i}{2}\right)}{\sum_{i=1}^n l_i}\\
&=\frac{\sum_{1\leq j<i\leq n} l_i l_j+\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{l^2_i}{2}}{\sum_{i=1}^n l_i}=\frac{(\sum_{i=1}^n l_i)^2}{2\sum_{i=1}^n l_i}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n l_i}{2}
\end{align}$$
which means that $c-\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n l_i}{2}\leq a.$
In a similar way, we show that $b\leq c+\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n l_i}{2}$ and we are done,
$$\bigcup_{i=1}^n I_i=[a,b]\subset \left[c-\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n l_i}{2},c+\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n l_i}{2}\right].$$